# Windows Server - redirect all DNS lookups to a specific address

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, windows-server-2016, captive-portal

This is using Windows Server 2016, Linux is not an option in this case.

I need to set up something like a captive portal but much simpler. I have a Windows Server machine set up to advertise a WiFi hotspot, and when users connect to that WiFi hotspot they must only be able to get to one locally hosted web page, regardless of what address they type into the address bar.

It's simpler than a captive portal in that it's not necessary to ever allow the user full internet access (the Windows Server machine has no internet connection in any case).

The Windows Server machine is running DHCP, DNS and IIS, but I can't find a way (presumably using DNS) to make this work. Can anyone point me to some useful article or just some rough outline of how this could work? I'd be fine with some 3rd party utility but most of them seem to be overkill for such a simple requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new primary Forward Lookup Zone `.` and there just one record `* IN A 198.51.100.1` with your web server IP address. That makes it handle every DNS query as if it was authoritative.

Of course this only works if this DNS server doesn't need to resolve recursively for anyone else. Probably it doesn't as you mentioned that it doesn't have any Internet connection at all.